# File operations freeze when putting files larger than 10MB on an SD card

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, filemanager

I have the newest Ubuntu 13 with all updates.

When copying files to my 32GB SD card, the file operations freeze just before it finishes. It does not complete. Files greater than 10MB do this. Smaller files have no problems.

Comment: forgot to add: flash drive does this too. not just sd card. Windows 8(the other os i have dualbooting) does not do this

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: The OP [says he switched back to Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291177/file-operations-freeze-when-putting-files-larger-than-10mb-on-an-sd-card#comment372795_291315).

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed about your hardware. It happened to me too. The speed of your processor also contributes to the speed of transferring files.

Check your RAM and swap space. Before this, I had 2GB of RAM.  After I upgraded it to 4GB of RAM, copying files was faster and smooth.  You also need to have large of swap space.

I transferred 200GB file from HDD to my Ubuntu 13.04. The larger the file, the slower it gets. UPGRADE! Just my experience.

Comment: i have a newer computer. Windows does not do this. So the only fix is to never use Ubuntu again. Goodbye forever Ubuntu